# What does apply_filters() do exactly?

Tags: widgets

I'm new to WordPress development and was just thinking of adding some functionality to a widget. I have been seeing some people using this:

```
$title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', empty( $instance['title'] ) ? '' : $instance['title'], $instance, $this->id_base );
```

And some people this:

```
$title = ( $instance['title'] ) ? $instance['title'] : '';
```

In my case I want to add a link to a button but I am not sure if I should use apply filters on it or not.

```
$buttonLink = ( $intance['buttonlink'] ) ? $intance['buttonlink'] : '';
```

Comment: The brackets around `$intance` (which is missing an `s`) are not necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$instance['title']` corresponds to the title enter in the widget.

When a plugin or a widget as an apply_filters, the developper gently had a way to override the current value sets for the title.

Now, imagine you setted a title (in the widget setting panel) but you want to change this value only if user is logged in. You just have to add a filter in your functions.php

```
add_filter('widget_title', 'logged_title');

function logged_title($title){
    if(is_user_logged_in()){ // don't forget to test your widget id 
        $title = 'new widget title';
    }
    return $title;
}
```